# Should I be using LightOpenID?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, google-authentication, lightopenid

OpenID appears to be deprecated according to Google's information here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable

What does this mean for developers currently using LightOpenID? Does LightOpenID use deprecated authentication methods with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's not apparent, Google's deprecation isn't a general deprecation of OpenID, but for them specifically; they want developers to migrate to their Google+.